# undefined reference to `__libm_sse2_sincos' & undefined reference to `__libm_sse2_pow'

Tags: c, gcc, linker, libraries, icc

I have some core libraries compiled in icc  and I am using those libraries to build my code with the help of gcc.

I have included the `-lm` in linking command but I am still getting he following undefined references:

> undefined reference to `__libm_sse2_sin`
> undefined reference to `__libm_sse2_sincos`
> undefined reference to `__libm_sse2_pow`

Does anyone know how to resolve this? According to my investigation this is happening due to  use of different compilers but using icc instead of gcc is not an option for me.

Is there any extra library I need to add which have definition for these undefined references?

Comment: Perhaps you need `libmmd.lib` or `libmmd.dll` but IDK if gcc has them.

Comment: i didnot find libmmd.lib for gcc... is there any other solution...:) ?